# Submit record in 2 databases

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form and I want to submit the form data in 2 databases. But the problem is: both the databases are on different servers. I am new to mysql so I don't know exactly how to do that. I am working in php. I am sharing my code with you, its not working properly. so please check this out:

```
$con = mysql_connect('differenthost','user1','pass1');
mysql_select_db('dbname1',$con);

$path = "misc/classified/".$submiturl;

mysql_query("insert into tablename1 (title,description,status,parent_id,path) values ('$submiturl','$submiturl','active','68','$path')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);

mysql_connect('localhost','user2','pass2');
mysql_select_db('dbname2');

$check = mysql_query("select count(*) from tablename2 where userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' and datecreated = '$datecreated'") or die(mysql_error());
```

This error comes when I submit the form:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Unknown MySQL server host 'differenthost' (25) in /home/class/public_html/microworker/submiturl.php on line 11

Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/class/public_html/microworker/submiturl.php on line 12

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'user2'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/class/public_html/microworker/submiturl.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/class/public_html/microworker/submiturl.php on line 16
Access denied for user 'user2'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What is the right syntax?

Comment: Check your db connections first.

Comment: I used dummy names here for security purposes, so overall error is that it submits in local server but did not submit on second server.

Comment: Your error is about the connection with database server. May be due to wrong credentials. Your remote server allows external connection?

Comment: @user2226181 security purpose? security? You use mysql_query() which is not sure at all and you don't use prepared statements to protect your queries, you might as-well just send a mass email, inviting people to take down your website.

Answer (score 1):

in your connection string you are using wrong server name

```
$con = mysql_connect('differenthost','user1','pass1');
```

user localhost as your server name

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','user1','pass1');
```

and should your full code

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','user1','pass1');
        mysql_select_db('dbname1',$con);

        $path = "misc/classified/".$submiturl;

        mysql_query("insert into tablename1 (title,description,status,parent_id,path) values ('$submiturl','$submiturl','active','68','$path')") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_close($con);

        mysql_connect('localhost','user2','pass2');
        mysql_select_db('dbname2');

        $check = mysql_query("select count(*) from tablename2 where userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' and datecreated = '$datecreated'") or die(mysql_error());
```

or if you are using a remote host then check the host name

Comment: Sourabh, both the database are not on same server, so how can you say that both server names are localhost?

Comment: u are using it on website ?

Comment: and y your are using both database on different server ?

Answer (score 1):

'localhost' connects you to the database on the same server. To access a db on a different server provide its actual host instead of 'differenthost'.

Then when you connect to the second server (call mysql_connect for the second time), get and save the connection value and then each time for each new query you will not need to reconnect again. As you know to the finction mysql_query you can pass the second parameter - and it's the link to the database.

And switch to the newer extension MySQLi, this one will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Unknown MySQL server host 'differenthost' (25) in /home/class/public_html/microworker/submiturl.php on line 11
```

clearly shows that your application is unable to connect to the database. Try to give the correct  *hostname* and/or *username/password* in this line

```
$con = mysql_connect('differenthost','user1','pass1');
```

Comment: Now this error is occurring

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'direc_esyndb'@'mylord.websitewelcome.com' (using password: YES) in /home/class/public_html/microworker/submiturl.php on line 11

Comment: May be you should also check for the configurations of the database i.e. your database has the _permissions_ to connect.

Comment: The problem is I did not add the server name into my remote host so that's why I cannot access to that server. So the solution is

If you want to access the other server database then you have to add their server name in your remote server feature.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should check to see if your connection succeeds. You are getting connection errors in the first instance.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

used this code

**you can used $con and  $con2 in mysql_query as second parameter**

```
$con = mysql_connect('differenthost','user1','pass1');
mysql_select_db('dbname1',$con);

$path = "misc/classified/".$submiturl;

mysql_query("insert into tablename1 (title,description,status,parent_id,path) values ('$submiturl','$submiturl','active','68','$path')",$con) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);

$con2 = mysql_connect('localhost','user2','pass2');
mysql_select_db('dbname2');

$check = mysql_query("select count(*) from tablename2 where userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' and datecreated = '$datecreated'",$con2) or die(mysql_error());
```

**take refernce of this**

You can make multiple calls to `mysql_connect()`, but if the parameters are the same you need to pass true for the '`$new_link`' (fourth) parameter, otherwise the same connection is reused.

so then you have

```
$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);
```

Then to query database 1, do this:

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh1);
```

and for database 2:

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh2);
```

Alternatively, if the mysql user has access to both databases and they are on the same host (i.e. both DBs are accessible from the same MySQL connection) you could:

- Keep one connection open and keep calling `mysql_select_db()` to swap between. I don't think this is a clean solution and you will easily get cases where you query the wrong db etc.
- Use queries where you specify the database name (e.g. `SELECT * FROM database2.tablename`), but this is again likely to be a pain to implement.

Also read troelskn's answer about using PDO instead because that is probably a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in saving in 2 databases, but in connection configuration.

Make sure that "differenthost" is accessible, and MySQL port is open (usually it is 3306).

Also, mysql_connect is deprecated in PHP 5.5, I suggest using PDO instead.